# proxychains suddenly stopped working

Tags: homebrew, proxy

When I run some program with [proxychains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/), it shows an error like below:

```
%> proxychains brew update
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.11
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.11
dyld: warning: could not load inserted library '/usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/proxychains-ng/4.11/lib/libproxychains4.dylib' into library validated process because no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/proxychains-ng/4.11/lib/libproxychains4.dylib: mmap() error 1 at address=0x10E5A3000, size=0x00006000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/proxychains-ng/4.11/lib/libproxychains4.dylib
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.11
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

1. Uninstall proxychains-ng `brew uninstall proxychains-ng`.
2. proxychains-ng need Xcode 7.x to build, build with Xcode 8 will cause this problem. Run `xcode-select` to change Xcode command line tool version, in my case `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode7.app/Contents/Developer`.
3. Reinstall proxychains-ng `brew install proxychains-ng`.

Comment: It is `proxychains-ng`, and I have xcode 8 installed.

Comment: proxychains need Xcode 7.x to build, 
Build with Xcode 8 will cause this problem.